Count of variable from merged sources
I have a Web Intelligence report which draws from two sources: A universe (containing my real data) and a table I use to convert ranges of values from the universe to aggregate groups.  Think converting entries with zip codes to state names.
I can get a table with a count of occurrences of each zip code, but I can't figure out how to get a count of each state instead.  My best effort makes a table listing state names and a value of 1 for each, or the number of zip codes for each state in the conversion table added to the number I actually want.
I'm new to WebI but I've done a fair bit with SQL.  What I'm trying to do is a left inner join from my universe to my zip-to-state table, group by state, and sum.  I can't alter the universe, so it needs to be report level.  What am I doing wrong?

Okay, I figured it out after much headdesking.
I needed to Count() the unique identifiers for each item in the table, not the field I was interested in; the software automatically groups or for me.  I.e., if I had a unique order ID for each order,  I would use =[StateName] for my first column (getting the state groups) and then =Count([OrderID]) in the second column, to count the number of orders in that state.
Easy, just not intuitive (for me, anyway).
